# Can I somehow split one single file between drives? Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sparsefile

I want to split a bigger file (virtual machine disk) between my available drives.
Is it possible? If so, how would one do it?

Simple use case: In today's world, you may have many different drives in your system and they might not be in RAID. If you could split the image between 2-3 SSD drives, you could increase the available space and potentially the speed as well. In theory, this all seems "doable", but the theory is often vastly different from reality.

Ps.: I've tried to do RAID inside virtual guests and this works, but it can be a pain. On FreeBSD, it takes like 2 seconds to set up and it works out of the box. On Linux it's cumbersome, to say the least. Some distros will have some basic support for `mdadm`, some won't have any at all. And Windows, oh Windows. There is zero support for anything like this on Windows. You can only do basic RAID1, or Storage Spaces, but forget about doing RAID0 on boot drives.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes and no.

You cannot break a file in two, but you can create 2 harddisk files and then in the Guest OS merge them as one disk.

Your question mentions that you are aware of this but are looking for a different solution.

Another option is to do the same on OS level. Span a partition over multiple disks so that the partition image is large enough to hold the entire disk image. The downside here is that you will need to repartition your disks, and thus they need to be emptied.

There is no way to somehow magically split a file in multiple chunks and make your OS understand where different chunks live. Yes, you can use something like 7zip to create an archive that spans multiple files and place each section on a different partition, but as it is an archive now, the content itself is not available until the archive is extracted.

Comment: That's sad. And that's the problem. It's easy to raid them in BSD, but oh god, does it get worse on other platforms. And of course, I'd need it for Windows. Wish there was like a "fake raid card" for VMs...

Comment: In Windows, you can convert to a dynamic disks, and to my understanding linux does recognize dynamic disks nowadays.